# Allocate (deallocate) managed package licenses to users via Apex

Tags: apex, licenses, lma

Our salesforce is integrated with a third party that activates and deactivates users on a daily basis.

Given this situation, it would be ideal that licenses for managed packages are allocated/de-allocated automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it is only possible to [manually allocate managed package user licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/distribution_assigning_user_licenses.htm).

> "The bridge between The "manage Licenses" Section of the Installed App and the actual User Record is not reachable on the platform..." Ideas: [Managed Package License Reporting](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hjUGAAY)

Comment: +1 to this. I've worked at two ISVs now and can confirm there's nothing allowing anybody to programmatically assign licenses.

Answer (score 5):

I know it is marked as an Answer because probably at that time this function wasn't yet devised by Salesforce, I'm adding the link for anyone coming to this question like I did today :-) ...

[Assigning Licenses using the API](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=package_license_api.htm&language=en_US)

Also take a look at the Idea here [Exposing License Management Objects to API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kvq4AAA) and see the latest Comment from Product Management with some details.